# Scilab Error: Mean, Variance not executing

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scilab

I1 is an rgb image. 'Out' variable basically stores one colour channel of the whole image.

The in-built functions mean, variance and standard deviation when calculated on 'out' gives an error asking for a real vector or matrix as input.

This can be seen in image given below[image: here]

But when min or max is used, no error is reported.But these in-built function take in the same parameters as mentioned in the Scilab documentation which is of type vector or matrix of integers.

On further examination, it seems that variable 'out' is of type matrix of graphic handles when it should be a matrix of integers.
I can't seem to understand why the error is coming if it works for min and max functions ?

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `imread()` is a hypermatrix of integers, not of floating point numbers.

This is shown by the fact that `min(out)` is displayed as `"4"` (without decimal point), not as `"4."`
Now, `mean()` and `stdev()` do not work with integers, only with real or complex numbers.

The solution is to convert integers into decimal numbers:

```
mean(double(out))
```

https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.1/en_US/double.html